# Get complete last row of `df` output

Tags: disk-usage, command, tail

I would like to execute the command

```
df -h /etc/nginx/access_log_backup_directory/ | tail -1
```

Depending on the file system lenth the command `df -h /etc/nginx/access_log_backup_directory/` gives the output as follows in one case:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       50G   28G   19G  60% /
```

and in another case:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/xxxxxxxxxxxx
                       29G  4.1G   24G  15% /
```

So I am not able to do `tail -1` where I can get complete last row with file system name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use the [`-P` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/df-invocation.html#df-invocation), it ensures that each filesystem's information is presented on one line:

```
df -hP /etc/nginx/access_log_backup_directory/ | tail -1
```